# What conditions must apply for functions $f$ and $g,$ so that $f(g) = g(f)?$

Tags: functional-equations

I have found some solutions, but nothing general. The solutions are
$f=g;
f = g^{-1};
f(x)=x;
f(x)=ax, g(x)=bx,$ for any $a$ and $b;$
I am unable to find any solutions other than these, or to prove that none exist.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your question would benefit from some additional context. For example, do your functions take real arguments? Are they real valued?

Comment: Have you heard about inverse of a function?

Comment: that's one of the solutions I wrote in my description, sorry for not making it clear enough. If f and g are each other's inverses, then the condition is satisfied, but that's not the only solution to this functional equation.

Comment: to clarify, the only restriction for the functions is that they have to take real values and output real values.

Comment: Well $f(x)=x^n$ and $g(x)=x^m$ seem to work.

Comment: yeah, they work too, thanks for an answer!

Comment: $g=f\circ f\circ\cdots\circ f.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that's much less trivial, than the ones I though up, thanks!

Comment: You can also start with any $h$ and use $f=h\circ h\cdots \circ h$ $m$ times, and $g=h\circ h\circ\cdots \circ h$ $n$ times. Or, if $h$ is invertible, then $g=h^{-1}\circ h^{-1}\circ \cdots \circ h^{-1}$ $n$ times.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that's a nice generalization